# SSLHandShake checkServerTrusted called 3 times in Android 7 Nougat

Tags: java, android, ssl, https, x509trustmanager

What might be the reason why checkServerTrusted of TrustManager is called 3 times in 1 request? Is there some sort of "resending" of Client Hello message if the first startHandShake failed in Android?

Update:
When I'm using specific ciphers in (which in Android 5, the handshake is completed), checkServerTrusted is only called once.

Comment: how big is your certifacate-chain? a little bit more context is required, how did you see the 3 calls, if by debugger you can check the parameters given on functioncall

Comment: @Fusselchen I print something inside my checkServerTrusted method and it is printed 3 times. The certificate chain is only 1.

Also please check my update. Might help.